# why I can't close the session in firebase with google

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi my problem is because I can't close the session in firebase with google I use this

```
logout() {
      this.firebase
      .auth
      .signOut();
  }
```

I log in with google but when I log out and I log in again the previous session is open, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the previous session is open"? What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I log in with google but when I log out and I log in again with any google account or the same google account the last session is open, I think the log out doesn't work fine

Comment: I use the method above

Comment: What does "the last session is open" mean? Please be detailed, giving a step by step description of what happens vs what you expected to happen.

Comment: I have a button to log in with google when I want to log in I press this button and I have a button when I want to log out I use the method above, I'm using angular 7. The problem that I have is because when I press the log out button everything looks fine I'm redirected to the log in page but when I want to log in again with google the last session in my browser is still open, I mean I press again the log in button with google and I'm redirected to the home page with the same last account without enter any credentials

Comment: my problem is the same when you don't close the session of your email, I have to explain anything else? please tell me

Comment: I think this is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320147/logout-from-google-after-login-out-from-firebase